# monaca Google Map 実機(iPhone)で現在地が取得できない。

Tags: monaca, iphone

monaca で Google map APIを読み込み、
現在地を取得して地図を表示しています。

現在地の取得には navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() を
使っています。

PCのブラウザーや monacaデバッガーで
動作させた場合は 問題なく表示できるのですが、

実機検証のため iOS用にAdHocビルドを行い、iPhoneで試したところ、
現在地の取得でエラーになってしまい、地図が表示できません。

尚、起動時に読み込んでいるスクリプトは以下の通りです。

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<script src="js/ncmb-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/zepto.min.js"></script>
```

ncmb-1.2.6.min.jsのバージョンが 2.0.n でないのは、ファイルストアを使用するためです。
zepto.min.js はjQueryの代わりに（軽量版ということで）使っています。

何か足りないのでしょうか？
ご教授お待ちしております。

Comment: 実機の場合、onError が呼び出されます。
引数messageの内容をAlert(message); で表示すると
[object Position Error]でした。

Comment: 上記は、
var option = { frequency: 5000, timeout: 6000 }; navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, option); として、onSuccess, onError とも alert(); を入れて確認しました。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。

MonacaクラウドIDE→ファイル→Cordovaプラグインの管理→Geolocationのプラグインを有効にしたら、実機での現在地が取得できました。

同様にお困りの方の参考になれば幸いです。